# Is it possible to modify arrow damage in Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

It seems there will be a NBT tag in minecraft 1.9 that will allow to set custom damage. In the meanwhile, is there a way to do it in previous versions?

Comment: Detect when the player is hit and deal additional damage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can modify arrow damage with the `damage` tag of the [Arrow entity](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Arrow). This has been present since the power enchantment was added.

E.g.

```
/summon Arrow ~ ~5 ~ {damage:10}
```

Comment: You can use `entitydata` on a fast clock to set the damage of all arrows in the game (except super-point blank shots). Note: Doing this will override any Power enchantments placed on the bow.

Comment: You could also use stats to detect when someone uses a bow, then change the nearest arrow's damage based on the enchant on the bow they are holding, if power is important

Comment: Does it mean that I cannot give item arrows with the damage tag?

Comment: @Lionitow Yes, arrow items do not have this tag. There are ways to work around this though. You could use `execute` on players that have just shot a bow and have these special arrows to change the data of arrows in their immediate vicinity.

Comment: @MrLemon Wouldn't that mean an unbuffed player shooting a buffed player could still get the buff?

Comment: @acbabis theoretically, yes. But note that entitydata is only called in the same tick as the shooter fires (using a `stat.useItem.bow` objective). It will take some testing to determine the minimal radius around the shooter in which this will still work, but if that is small enough, the chance to enhance incoming arrows should be tolerably low (I could be wrong though).

Comment: 1.13 updates to previous comments: you use `/data merge entity` instead of `/entitydata` and `minecraft.used:minecraft.bow` instead of `stat.useItem.bow`.